# Issue with io.github.resilience4j version 1.7.2 (SpelResolverConfigurationOnMissingBean.spelResolver() method that does not exist)

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, resilience4j, resilience4j-retry

I'm using io.github.resilience4j. Everything is working fine with 1.6.1 version but when upgraded to 1.7.1 version my application is not running. Please find my code changes below.

My pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is application.propertes changes

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.slidingWindowSize= 10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.minimumNumberOfCalls=5
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState= 3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.default.eventConsumerBufferSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.slidingWindowSize=100
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=30
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.waitDurationInOpenState=1s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.configs.shared.eventConsumerBufferSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.profile.registerHealthIndicator=true
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.profile.slidingWindowSize=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.profile.minimumNumberOfCalls=10
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.profile.permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState=3
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.profile.waitDurationInOpenState=5s
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.profile.failureRateThreshold=50
resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.profile.eventConsumerBufferSize=10

resilience4j.retry.configs.default.maxAttempts=3
resilience4j.retry.configs.default.waitDuration=100
resilience4j.retry.instances.profile.baseConfig=default

resilience4j.bulkhead.configs.default.maxConcurrentCalls=30
resilience4j.bulkhead.configs.instances.profile.maxWaitDuration=10ms
resilience4j.bulkhead.configs.instances.profile.maxConcurrentCalls=20

resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead.configs.default.maxThreadPoolSize=4
resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead.configs.default.coreThreadPoolSize=2
resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead.configs.default.queueCapacity=2
resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead.instances.profile.maxThreadPoolSize=1
resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead.instances.profile.coreThreadPoolSize=1
resilience4j.thread-pool-bulkhead.instances.profile.queueCapacity=1

resilience4j.ratelimiter.configs.default.registerHealthIndicator=false
resilience4j.ratelimiter.configs.default.limitForPeriod=10
resilience4j.ratelimiter.configs.default.limitRefreshPeriod=1s
resilience4j.ratelimiter.configs.default.timeoutDuration=0
resilience4j.ratelimiter.configs.default.eventConsumerBufferSize=100

resilience4j.timelimiter.configs.default.cancelRunningFuture=false
resilience4j.timelimiter.configs.default.timeoutDuration=2s
resilience4j.timelimiter.instances.profile.baseConfig=default
```

Here is controller API changes

```
private static final String PROFILE="profile";    


@GetMapping("/{programType}/profile")
@AdobeIOAuthentication
@RateLimiter(name = PROFILE)
@TimeLimiter(name = PROFILE)
@CircuitBreaker(name = PROFILE)
@Bulkhead(name = PROFILE)
```

Error I'm getting while getting building

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-08-11 14:37:21.503 IST ERROR requestId=NA x-correlation-id=NA 17200 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    io.github.resilience4j.spelresolver.autoconfigure.SpelResolverConfigurationOnMissingBean.spelResolver(SpelResolverConfigurationOnMissingBean.java:54)

The following method did not exist:

    'io.github.resilience4j.spelresolver.SpelResolver io.github.resilience4j.spelresolver.configure.SpelResolverConfiguration.spelResolver(org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser, org.springframework.core.ParameterNameDiscoverer, org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory)'

The method's class, io.github.resilience4j.spelresolver.configure.SpelResolverConfiguration, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/169576/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring/1.6.0/resilience4j-spring-1.6.0.jar!/io/github/resilience4j/spelresolver/configure/SpelResolverConfiguration.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    io.github.resilience4j.spelresolver.configure.SpelResolverConfiguration: file:/C:/Users/169576/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring/1.6.0/resilience4j-spring-1.6.0.jar
```

Can some one please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: You are mixing jars from different versions... *resilience4j-spring-1.6.0.jar* is not really 1.7.

Comment: Can you please explain where I did the mistake?

Comment: No as I don't know which depndencies you use. But you only upgraded part of the dependencies.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try version 1.7.0

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `resilience4j-spring-boot2` contains `resilience4j-core` but downgrade to version `1.7.0` helps, I assume Spring boot version is missing something I have `2.5.6`

Comment: I had the same problem with `1.7.1` and downgrading to `1.7.0` worked for me as well.  Spring boot `2.6.1` here.

Comment: I got the same issue when setting `1.7.1` version explicitly with Spring Boot `2.6.3`. Downgrading to `1.7.0` fixed it. 
FWIW: when using Gradle, I also noticed this issue doesn't happen if we skip the version and leave the dependency configuration to the plugin: 
`implementation 'io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2'`

Comment: Same version 1.7.0 works with the Spring-Boot version 2.6.6

Comment: Same with Spring Boot 2.7.11:  downgrading from 1.7.1 to 1.7.0 worked.  *BUT WHY?*

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue. I update also to version 1.7.0 but it not works.
I saw that the log information is show version to reference like that:

io.github.resilience4j.spelresolver.configure.SpelResolverConfiguration: file:/C:/Users/169576/.m2/repository/io/github/resilience4j/resilience4j-spring/1.6.0/resilience4j-spring-**1.6.0**.jar

We need only follow on log and update version to 1.6.0 means that same version in log